# how to set value of property in constructor (explicit interface implementation)

Tags: c#, interface

```
[DataContract]
public class OrderSyncData : ISync
{

    public OrderSyncData(Order o)
    {
        this.CurrentOrderStatus = o.DriverStatus;
        this.StatusDescription = o.StatusDescription;
        SyncTimestamp = o.SyncTimestamp; ????
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string CurrentOrderStatus { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
    [DataMember]// I don't think I need these any more
    public bool IsCanceled { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsResolved { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsPendingResponse { get; set; }

    DateTime ISync.SyncTimestamp { get; set; }
}
```

How to set the value of ISync.SyncTimestamp? I tried casting the "this." but it doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
((ISync)this).SyncTimestamp = o.SyncTimestamp;
```

Note the extra braces around `(ISync)this`.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to cast `this`:

```
((ISync) this).SyncTimestamp = o.SyncTimestamp;
```

Or you could do it in two statements:

```
ISync sync = this;
sync.SyncTimestamp = o.SyncTimestamp;
```

Basically, the explicit interface implementation means that the property is only available when you're viewing `this` in the context of simply `ISync`, not the implementation class.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've implemented `SyncTimestamp` explicitly. Explicit implementations cannot be accessed from a class instance. Why? Because explicit implementation allows you to implement multiple interfaces with the same member name.

```
class Foo: IBar, IFoo
{
    bool IBar.FooBar {get;set;}
    bool IFoo.FooBar {get;set;}
}
```

Then writing `this.FooBar` refers to which implementation? So either you cast `this` to the desired interface explicitly, like other answers suggest, or you don't implement the `SyncTimestamp` explicitly, but do it implicitly: `public DateTime SyncTimestamp { get; set; }`.
Then `this.SyncTimestamp` will work.